# MySQL JSON_EXTRACT() Query returns null

Tags: mysql, json, extract

I have the following `JSON-File` in a `MYSQL` Database:

```
[
{
    "order" : 0,
    "value" : 0.168257
},
{
    "order" : 0.031250,
    "value" : 0.002387
},
{
    "order" : 0.062500,
    "value" : 0.002367
},
{
    "order" : 0.093750,
    "value" : 0.002365
},
{
    "order" : 0.125000,
    "value" : 0.002369
},
{
    "order" : 0.156250,
    "value" : 0.002384
   },
   {
    "order" : 0.187500,
    "value" : 0.002403
   }
]
```

I would like to Query and get the result for "order"=0.156250
I use the following Query:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(jsonColumn,'$.order') ... WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jsonColumn,'$.order') = 0.156250
```

It is not working. 
I can only select the Column by doing the following:

```
Select JSON_EXTRACT(jsonColumn,'$[5].order')
```

Can somebody tell me how to select the Column without giving the `index` to the Select statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Also, are the values numeric or strings?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7 or 8.0?

Comment: MySQL Version 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert this to `json_table` first before filtering

```
select *
     from
test t1
cross join 
       json_table(t1.jsonColumn,
         "$[*]"
         columns(
           `Order` numeric(9,6) path "$.order",        
           `Value` numeric(9,6) path "$.value"
         )
       ) t2
where t2.Order = 0.156250
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWif2AAexHAVMFKzxjYeoz/0#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z)

for `mySQL` versions **5.7**

```
select
  *  
from test t1  
cross join ( 
  select  1 as col1 union
  select  2 union
  select  3 union
  select  4 union
  select  5 union
  select  6   
  ) t2
where json_extract(t1.jsonColumn, concat('$[', t2.col1, '].order')) = 0.156250;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWif2AAexHAVMFKzxjYeoz/0#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z)